# What's the difference between create_before and initialise in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to set a data when a object is created. Currently I use two ways:

**Using before_create**

```
before_create :set_number

def set_number
  self.number = Random.new.rand(1..1000)
end
```

**Override initialize**

```
def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
  super
  self.number = Random.new.rand(1..1000)
end
```

What's the difference between them, and is there any better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initialize` is triggered on `Object#new`. Before any of the callback methods are triggered. More importantly `before_create` gets called after all the validation has occurred.

I don't recommend overriding `initialize`. Instead you could use the `after_initialize` hook.

However, I don't see the point of spending precious computing cycles generating a random number every time you do `MyObject.new` (unless you explicitly need to do it). You'd probably want to generate it when you are persisting the object. So I would use:

`before_validation :set_number, on: :create`